# How to simplify polynomial to get to particular factor?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

If I have an expression like this

```
ex = -l + l t - 2 t^2 + T + (l - 2 t) y
```

This can be written as

```
ex1 = -l + (l - 2 t) (t + y) + T
```

However, if I try

```
FullSimplify[ex]
```

I get

```
T + l (-1 + t + y) - 2 t (t + y)
```

How can I get the form of `ex1` without having to manually copy, paste and modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some work around until a smarter and more automatic solution shows up, will delete.

The term `-l + T` is making it not see the simplification. So one way is to remove the bad term, simplify, then add it back in

```
badTerm = (-l + T);
Simplify[ex - (badTerm)] + badTerm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, using `l` for variable name is not good idea, it looks almost like `1`